# Bash script to edit lots of html documents

Tags: bash, shell-script, html

I have a directory with many HTML documents. Most of them contain the codeblock

```html
      .org-link {
        /* org-link */
        color: #b58900;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: underline;
      }
```

inside the `<style type="text/css">` tag. I'd like to write a script that removes the line `text-decoration: underline;` from this block in every file.

Usually I would write a `sed` or `perl` one-liner to simply delete each instance of `text-decoration: underline;` but many of the documents have other instances of the line `text-decoration: underline` that I do not removed.

Is there a tool in linux that can easily do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed '/.org-link {/,/}/{/text-decoration: underline;/d}' file
```

Output:

```
      .org-link {
        /* org-link */
        color: #b58900;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
```

To edit your file "in place":

```
sed -i '/.org-link {/,/}/{/text-decoration: underline;/d}' file
```

Comment: I'm aware that `sed` or `perl` can do this. The problem is that there are other instances of `text-decoration: underline;` in the files that I don't want deleted. Maybe I should make this clear in my question.

Comment: Is there always a line with ".org-link {" to mark this block?

Comment: Yes. I want to delete the the first instance of `font-weight: bold;` after `.org-link {`

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how could I adjust the code if I wanted to replace this instance of `text-decoration: underline` with `text-decoration: bold`?

Comment: Replace the search and delete `/text-decoration: underline;/d` by a search and replace: `s/text-decoration: underline;/font-weight: bold;/`

Answer (score 0):

Using `gawk`:

```
gawk -i inplace '/.org-link {/,/}/ {if($0~/text-decoration: underline/) next} {print}' infile
```

This will delete only `text-decoration: underline` attributes in a `.org-link` class:

```
user@debian ~ % cat infile
.org-link {
        /* org-link */
        color: #b58900;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: underline;
      }

.org-link1 {
        /* org-link */
        color: #b58900;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: underline;
      }

.org-link {
        /* org-link */
        color: #b58900;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: underline;
      }
user@debian ~ % gawk -i inplace '/.org-link {/,/}/ {if($0~/text-decoration: underline/) next} {print}' infile
user@debian ~ % cat infile
.org-link {
        /* org-link */
        color: #b58900;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

.org-link1 {
        /* org-link */
        color: #b58900;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: underline;
      }

.org-link {
        /* org-link */
        color: #b58900;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
```

To loop this over multiple HTML files in the same working directory, you can use a `bash` `for` loop with wildcards:

```
for f in *.html; do gawk -i inplace '/.org-link {/,/}/ {if($0~/text-decoration: underline/) next} {print}' "$f"; done
```